# Trying to create a recyclerview which will be filtered with a searchview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview, android-databinding

I have been trying to get create a recyclerview that will be filtered with a searchview. It displays all the items on the List that I provide rather than filtering. I am also using data binding. I am making a big mistake or I am missing something. Any suggestions?

Here is my code.

FRAGMENT CLASS

```
    package com.batch.mcs.finalproject;

import android.arch.lifecycle.Observer;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.batch.mcs.finalproject.adapters.SearchFragmentRecyclerViewAdapter;
import com.batch.mcs.finalproject.databinding.FragmentSearchBinding;
import com.batch.mcs.finalproject.models.Group;
import com.batch.mcs.finalproject.viewmodel.AppViewModel;

import java.util.List;

public class SearchFragment extends BaseFragment {

    FragmentSearchBinding fragmentSearchBinding;
    View view;
    SearchFragmentRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public static SearchFragment getInstance(){
        return new SearchFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    fragmentSearchBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

    view = fragmentSearchBinding.getRoot();

    AppViewModel appViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AppViewModel.class);
    appViewModel.initMockGroups();
    appViewModel.getLiveGroupAll().observe(this, new Observer<List<Group>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Group> groups) {

            SearchView searchView = fragmentSearchBinding.svSearchLayout;
            search(searchView);

            adapter = new SearchFragmentRecyclerViewAdapter(groups, getContext());
            recyclerView = fragmentSearchBinding.rvSearchLayout;
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });

    return view;
}

private void search(SearchView searchView) {

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

SearchFragmentRecyclerViewAdapter  class

```
    package com.batch.mcs.finalproject.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.databinding.ViewDataBinding;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;

import com.batch.mcs.finalproject.BR;
import com.batch.mcs.finalproject.R;
import com.batch.mcs.finalproject.models.Group;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SearchFragmentRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchFragmentRecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private List<Group> groups;
    private List<Group> filteredGroups;
    private Context context;

    public SearchFragmentRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Group> groups, Context context){
        this.groups = groups;
        this.filteredGroups = groups;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_group_information_item,viewGroup, false);
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Group group = filteredGroups.get(position);
        holder.getBinding().setVariable(BR.groupItem, group);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return filteredGroups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();

                if(charString.isEmpty()){
                    filteredGroups = groups;
                } else {
                    List<Group> fGroups = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(Group g:fGroups){
                        if(g.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString)){
                            fGroups.add(g);
                        }
                        filteredGroups = fGroups;
                    }
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = filteredGroups;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                filteredGroups = (ArrayList<Group>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ViewDataBinding binding;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(itemView);
        }

        public ViewDataBinding getBinding() {
            return binding;
        }
    }
}
```

XML FILE

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <data>
        <variable
            name="User"
            type="com.batch.mcs.finalproject.models.User"/>
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="@style/AppTheme.ActivityLayoutStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/sv_search_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:maxLines="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rv_search_layout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_search_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/no_dimension"
            android:dividerHeight="@dimen/rv_search_group_margins"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sv_search_layout" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Method to Search in RecyclerView, Set this code in you Fragment, not in you Adapter.

```
searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                mAdapterSmall.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                mAdapterBig.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
```